# Image Uploader not working magento 1.8 due to Adobe flash outdated

Tags: php, magento-1.8

Since end of 2020 adobe flash player going outdated because of that,Magneto 1.8 version image upload function not working. is there any solution to fix this issue.

Here attached screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have two ways

either apply the **SUPEE 8788** patch based on your magento version

or

upgrade the Magento version to the latest one at least above 1.9.3.x.

Comment: Thank you very much. i will try it